# How to scale an ImageView to larger than its parent in Android?

Tags: android, android-gesture

The goal would be like what Instagram already has. When zooming/scaling an image/video on the main feed, the media content would be able to scale out of its parent boundaries. I've tried different approaches but always limited to inside of the parent layout only.

Comment: in xml or compose?

Comment: in xml ideally.

Comment: did you try: https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/animations/zoom ?

Comment: I found this too but this isn't what I was looking for. I don't have a "hidden" image on the screen. The imageView will be an item in a RecyclerView.